# Looking for Vertical Menu bar using bootstrap 3.0

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I was looking for any plugin or ng module for the menu like below one. I want to show only images on hover. I wanted to check if there is any available plugin before start implementing the logic for it

http://www.gv.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap site has examples, one of them include a vertical side-nav.  You could just replace the text links with images and resize it to your needs.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/